# Why do we have to put the connection string in app.config?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, web.config-transform

i just started my first mvc4 solution. i have created 2 projects. the first is an MVC4 project and it contains all the controllers (it is the web app) and the second is only for Models, classes and Entity Framework data access.

i would like to know why do i need to put the connection string in app.config (in data access) as long as the same connection string is in the web.config?

i am worried about the debug and release configuration because till now i am only capable of transforming the connection string in web.config but not in app.config? i don't want to publish settings and start making tests on a production environment because of that connection string in app.config.

hope my question is clear!

Comment: You don't actually have to put the connection string in a config file at all. You could embed it in your code (although that's not a good idea) or retrieve it from a central database or from an API or a custom file format. It's really up to you and what works best for your project.

Comment: actualy i want to retrieve it from a central db but at the moment the web.config is enough for my project

Comment: Why are you using MVC 4? That's old. Are you sure you're not using .NET 4 with MVC 5?

Comment: yes MVC4 i still haven't had the time to start with MVC5

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You should not start development with MVC 4. Are you getting MVC 5 confused with MVC 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put it in app.config.  In fact, app.config doesn't do anything in Class Library projects.

You should only put it in the config file for your actual app (Web.config for web, or app.config for EXEs).

Comment: actually yes. it seems that i don't need it!! but i was kind of sure that i needed it at the beginning for some reason. could it be related to the edmx file or the classes that are being updated from the database?

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes; the EDMX designer only looks in its own project.

Comment: ok thanks. so the EDMX designer will look in app.config to get the connection string and update the data model but my project is not going to use that connection string after publishing. my project will only use the connection string in web.config. did i get that right?